# if (schema == null || cd default!('pluralization' in schema.options)) // I'm using mongoose. What does this error mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to create a simple CRUD app. Wrote a simple create logic to save data in mongoDB atlas using mongoose.
[image]

Here is my model.js code (The file in which I take care of the mongoose schema and model)-

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        unique:true,
        required:true
    },
    gender:String,
    status:String
})

// var User=mongoose.model('User','userSchema');


module.exports=mongoose.model({collection:'Users'},'userSchema');
```

Here is my router.js code

```
route.post("/api/users",function(req,res){
    if(!req.body){
        res.status(400).send({message:"Content cannot be empty"});
        return;
    }
    //new user
    const userInstance=new User_({
        name:req.body.name,
        email:req.body.email,
        gender:req.body.gender,
        status:req.body.status
    })

    User_.save(userInstance).then(function(data){
        res.send(data);
    }).catch(err=>{
        res.status(500).send({message:err.message||"Some error occurred"})
    });

})
```

Please tell me what's wrong. I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

in model.js,  don't use quotes around userSchema

Instead use , module.exports=mongoose.model({collection:'Users'},userSchema);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) on how to format your answers.